# How can i call the dynamic page contents in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am making a website using Codeigniter

My models are as

- For Home Page: Home_model.php(Inside model folder)
- For About Page: About_model.php(Inside model folder)

I have one controller to handle all the pages with calling different methods inside Controller Class.

The home page model is working fine;but when i call the about page
the inner contents inside about page is giving error As: Message: Undefined variable: a
Whereas i am simply passing an array to the view of about page
I have used print_r($a) on the view but the error is same

---

### Controller Code:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('home_model');
            $this->load->model('about_model');
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }
    public function index(){
        $page = 'home';
        $test_cms['query']=$this->home_model->getcms();
        $test_cms['title'] = 'Home Page';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $page);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $test_cms);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$page);

    }
    public function home(){
    $page = 'home';
        $test_cms['query']=$this->home_model->getcms();
        $test_cms['title'] = 'Home Page';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $page);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $test_cms);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$page);
   }
   public function about(){
    $page = 'about';

        $a['dada']=$this->about_model->testabout();
        $data['title']='other page';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $page);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $a);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$page);
   }
 }
```

---

### Home Page Model

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model{
public function __construct()
{
 $this->load->database(); 
}
public function getcms() {
    $q = $this->db->query('select * from cms');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    return $data;
    }
}
```

}

---

### About Page Model

```
class About_model extends CI_Model{
public function testabout() {
    $about['content']="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    return $about;
  }
```

}

Every time when i call the about page it is loading header and footer contents correctly but inner contents of about page saying the variable is undefined.
whereas i am simply calling the array inside it.

I am beginner.Can you please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Comment: <?php print_r($a); ?>

Comment: I think u r using $a instead $dada in your aboutua view

Comment: No no u need to use $dada not $a... m I right na :)

Comment: yes you are right...........oh my god this was totally my blunder

Comment: Thanks sir..............

Comment: Mentioned not dont forget to chose best answer as accepted it will help to others... u have two options in answer .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments you are using

```
print_r($a);
```

In your aboutus view you need to use

```
print_r($dada);
```

Becuase you define `$dada` inside the `$a` array. And its define as `$dada` and `$a` is your array.

Comment: Thanks #devpro for easy description.I will remember next time.

Comment: @pandey dont forget to mark as accepted by click the left green tick it will help to others

Answer (score 2):

**Always pass data to view with `$data`**

```
$data['query'] = $this->home_model->getcms(); # change  $test_cms['query'] to $data['query']
$data['title'] = 'Home Page';
```

So accordingly change all

**In home_model.php**

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct()
    {
     $this->load->database(); 
    }

    public function getcms() 
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('select * from cms');
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $count = count($result);

        if (!empty($count)) {
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function home()
{
$page = 'home';
    $result = $this->home_model->getcms();
    if($result == false)
    {
        $data['query'] = "No data found"
    }
    else{
        $data['query'] = $result;
    }
    $data['title'] = 'Home Page';
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $page);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $test_cms);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer',$page);
}
```

**In view**

```
print_r($query);
```

Comment: Yes it best practice to use proper name either data or anything but readable.